# Трансформации в PyTorch. Как сохранить синхронизацию с target, если target это координаты пикселя на изображении?

Tags: python, pytorch

Я создают нейросеть в Pytorch, которая должна искать на изображении объекты (отвёрнутые от камеры лица). По факту мне нужны 4 координаты, для примера прилагаю изображение на котором помечены эти координаты. В pytorch есть хороший набор [трансформаторов](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/auto_examples/plot_transforms.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-plot-transforms-py), но проблема в том, что если трансформация связана с искажением изображения, то надо соответственно менять и target, иначе координаты не будут совпадать с нужным точкам. Как лучше это сделать? Возможно в PyTorch уже есть, реализованные для таких целей инструменты?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
А вот так выглядит target для этого изображения - это nympy массив

```
[[1253  368]
 [1251  589]
 [1386  579]
 [1368  800]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для решения своей задачи я использовал пакет albumentations, который на данный момент можно найти по этой ссылке:
https://albumentations.ai/docs/examples/example_keypoints/

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)